# printing java code nothing happens

Tags: java, printing

Hi all i have the code below, it complies just fine, no errors but it does not do anything, what it is meant to is print out a page saying

hello world
have a nice day

but nothing happens, what am i doing wrong ?

code :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Richard
 */
import java.io.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import javax.print.event.*;

public class printtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Open the image file

            String testData = "hello world \r\n have a nice day.";
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(testData.getBytes());
            DocFlavor flavor =  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE   ;


            //DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;     
            //DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.CHAR_ARRAY.TEXT_PLAIN;

            // Find the default service

            PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            System.out.println(service);

            // Create the print job
            DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
            Doc doc= new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);

            PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

            // Print it
            job.print(doc, null);

            pjDone.waitForDone();

            // It is now safe to close the input stream
            is.close();


        } catch (PrintException e) {
            System.out.println("print exception");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static class PrintJobWatcher {
        // true iff it is safe to close the print job's input stream
        boolean done = false;

        PrintJobWatcher(DocPrintJob job) {
            // Add a listener to the print job
            job.addPrintJobListener(new PrintJobAdapter() {
                public void printJobCanceled(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                    allDone();
                }
                public void printJobCompleted(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                    allDone();
                }
                public void printJobFailed(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                    allDone();
                }
                public void printJobNoMoreEvents(PrintJobEvent pje) {
                    allDone();
                }
                void allDone() {
                    synchronized (PrintJobWatcher.this) {
                        done = true;
                        PrintJobWatcher.this.notify();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public synchronized void waitForDone() {
            try {
                while (!done) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i have just done 
void main( String[] args)
printtest.main ({})

and it comes up with a window displaying :

Win32 Printer : HP988FD1 (HP Officejet Pro 8600)

and then does nothing, the job appears in the queue for a split second but then nothing happens, have re installed the drivers for the printers etc still no luck, does work fine with work and also the code below i have run and successfully printed a page from :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.text.*;
/**
* The PrintText application expands on the
* PrintExample application in that it images
* text on to the single page printed.
*/
public class PrintText implements Printable {
/**
* The text to be printed.
*/
private static final String mText = 
"Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this "
+ "continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated to the "
+ "proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in "
+ "a great civil war, testing whether that nation or any nation so "
+ "conceived and so dedicated can long endure. We are met on a great "
+ "battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of "
+ "that field as a final resting-place for those who here gave their "
+ "lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and "
+ "proper that we should do this. But in a larger sense, we cannot "
+ "dedicate, we cannot consecrate, we cannot hallow this ground." 
+ "The brave men, living and dead who struggled here have consecrated "
+ "it far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will "
+ "little note nor long remember what we say here, but it can never "
+ "forget what they did here. It is for us the living rather to be "
+ "dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here "
+ "have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here "
+ "dedicated to the great task remaining before us--that from these "
+ "honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which "
+ "they gave the last full measure of devotion--that we here highly "
+ "resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain, that this "
+ "nation under God shall have a new birth of freedom, and that "
+ "government of the people, by the people, for the people shall "
+ "not perish from the earth.";
/**
* Our text in a form for which we can obtain a
* AttributedCharacterIterator.
*/
private static final AttributedString mStyledText = new AttributedString(mText);
/**
* Print a single page containing some sample text.
*/
static public void main(String args[]) {
/* Get the representation of the current printer and 
* the current print job.
*/
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
/* Build a book containing pairs of page painters (Printables)
* and PageFormats. This example has a single page containing
* text.
*/
Book book = new Book();
book.append(new PrintText(), new PageFormat());
/* Set the object to be printed (the Book) into the PrinterJob.
* Doing this before bringing up the print dialog allows the
* print dialog to correctly display the page range to be printed
* and to dissallow any print settings not appropriate for the
* pages to be printed.
*/
printerJob.setPageable(book);
/* Show the print dialog to the user. This is an optional step
* and need not be done if the application wants to perform
* 'quiet' printing. If the user cancels the print dialog then false
* is returned. If true is returned we go ahead and print.
*/
boolean doPrint = printerJob.printDialog();
if (doPrint) {
try {
printerJob.print();
} catch (PrinterException exception) {
System.err.println("Printing error: " + exception);
}
}
}
/**
* Print a page of text.
*/
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int pageIndex) {
/* We'll assume that Jav2D is available.
*/
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
/* Move the origin from the corner of the Paper to the corner
* of the imageable area.
*/
g2d.translate(format.getImageableX(), format.getImageableY());
/* Set the text color.
*/
g2d.setPaint(Color.black);
/* Use a LineBreakMeasurer instance to break our text into
* lines that fit the imageable area of the page.
*/
Point2D.Float pen = new Point2D.Float();
AttributedCharacterIterator charIterator = mStyledText.getIterator();
LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(charIterator, g2d.getFontRenderContext());
float wrappingWidth = (float) format.getImageableWidth();
while (measurer.getPosition() < charIterator.getEndIndex()) {
TextLayout layout = measurer.nextLayout(wrappingWidth);
pen.y += layout.getAscent();
float dx = layout.isLeftToRight()? 0 : (wrappingWidth - layout.getAdvance());
layout.draw(g2d, pen.x + dx, pen.y);
pen.y += layout.getDescent() + layout.getLeading();
}
return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
}
```

Comment: This line `System.out.println(service);` doesn't work because service has no useful toString() method.  You can print out the service name with `service.getName()` but debug access to the text of the print job is a little tricky because that isn't stored as plain text.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i am very new at java so i do not understand, what is required for this t work

Comment: `HP988FD1 (HP Officejet Pro 8600) print exception Printer is not accepting job` ... Make sure the printing is on, has paper and is not displaying any errors.  Try printing to it from some other application

Comment: prints fine in word, no errors, is on, even switched printers

Comment: ok now i only get a window appearing saying : Win32 Printer : HP Deskjet F4200 series
and nothing else happens or is said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the `PrintService` API is waiting for the `InputStream` to be closed before finalising the print job.

Remove the `pjDone.waitForDone()` and see what happens (this worked just fine for me)

Comment: i have just tried this and even switch printers and am still getting the print exception
Printer is not accepting job.
Win32 Printer : HP Deskjet F4200 series

Comment: Sounds like an issue between your program and your printer

Comment: From my "little" research, the suggestion is to remove the printer driver and reinstall it, try having a look at [this](http://www.cpscomputerhelp.com/2010/06/java-error-javaawtprintprinterexception.html)

Comment: ok now i only get a window appearing saying : Win32 Printer : HP Deskjet F4200 series and nothing else happens or is said but it works fine if i send something from word, when sending the file from java the print queue appears in the corner of the task bar (windows 8) but no document ever appears in it

Comment: ok just had the print queue open and when i run the java program it literally flashes up in the print queue then disapears

Comment: thank you i will try the link you provided thank you will report back

Comment: still no luck even after reinstalling the driver, does the code above work ok for you on your system ?

Comment: Thank you for trying, i am still having no luck, i have successfully printed some text from java code but the above code is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem but to print a PDF, not a basic text. It was working finely on Linux (Fedora) but not on Windows. So if it may help any one, here is my solution:

I noticed that printers may not be able to deal with PDFs. I finally decided to use a third-party lib [Apache PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and it worked finely.

I wrote some example code in my answer for a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/39271053/935039, if it helps.