# PDF Java print : job sent in printer jobs queue but nothing prints

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a PDF document.
I can see the job in the printer queue, and then I see it disappear, like if the printer had finished its job.

But the problem is that nothing is printing.
I can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,null);
PrintService service = null;
for (String imprimante : listImprimantes){
    for( PrintService printService : printServices ) {
        Attribute[] attrs = printService.getAttributes().toArray();
        for (int j=0; j<attrs.length; j++) {
            String attrName = attrs[j].getName();
            String attrValue = attrs[j].toString();
            if (attrName.equals("printer-info")){
                if (attrValue.equals(imprimante)){
                    service = printService;
                    DocFlavor[] flavors = service.getSupportedDocFlavors();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
InputStream fi = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
DocPrintJob printJob = service.createPrintJob();
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fi, flavor, null);
try {
    if (doc != null) {
        printJob.print(doc, null);
    }
} 
catch (PrintException e1) {
    log.debug(e1.getMessage());
}
```

If anyone can help me on this...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: No I haven't. issue still ongoing

Comment: i'm facing same situation like yours (Windows 8) java 8 ,i tried @teemoo answer using apache PDF box and it's worked but its only applied for PDF format .

Comment: I am facing the same problem, is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late to answer but since I had the same problem I think it can help others to post my solution.

I have faced this problem on Windows (7), but not on Linux (Fedora), so my first action was to check the drivers setup.

Then, I saw that PDFs are not native processed by many printers. It is accepted but nothing is printed. From this, several solutions can be chosen:

1. Transform the PDF to a PS or something like that before sending it to the printer.
2. Use third-party lib, like [Apache PdfBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) (current version is 2.0.2).

I chose solution 2 and it works like a charm. The nice thing in this is that it also uses PrintService, with attributes, so you can deal with pages, printer trays and many options.

Here is a part of my code:

```
private boolean print(PrintService printService, InputStream inputStream, PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes)
    throws PrintException {

    try {
        PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintService(printService);
        job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdf));
        job.print(attributes);
        pdf.close();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        logger.error("Error when printing PDF file using the printer {}", printService.getName(), e);
        throw new PrintException("Printer exception", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error when loading PDF from input stream", e);
        throw new PrintException("Input exception", e);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to close your PDDocument object. Please do also mention the PDFBox version you're using. (hopefully 2.0.2)